# Recently getting Error: Invalid value for <path> attribute d=

Tags: svg, raphael

We have had an interactive site plan for one of our clients working for a couple years now which can be seen [here](http://www.southportoncapecod.com/site-plan/).

As of the past couple days, it is all of a sudden firing the error Error:

```
Invalid value for <path> attribute d="L194,814L193,803L201,803L202,813Z"
```

with multiple errors since it uses raphael.js to draw each unit with plot points from Wordpress. I for the life of me can't figure out why this all of a sudden stopped working and is causing this error and not drawing the units and how to fix it. If anyone could shine some light on this it would be greatly appreciated. Code below.

```
<script>
var ie = (function(){

    var undef,
        v = 3,
        div = document.createElement('div'),
        all = div.getElementsByTagName('i');

    while (
        div.innerHTML = '<!--[if gt IE ' + (++v) + ']><i></i><![endif]-->',
        all[0]
    );

    return v > 4 ? v : undef;

}());
    var plots = [];
    var points = [];
    var ISIE = /*@cc_on!@*/0;
    var is9 = navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE 9.0")==-1 ? true : false;
    window.curHouseModel = '';
    <?php
        $a = array(
            'post_type' => 'plot',
            'orderby'   =>  'date',
            'order' =>  'asc',
            'posts_per_page' => -1
        );
        $q = new WP_Query($a);
        $counter = 0;
        while($q->have_posts()):
            $q->the_post();
            ?>
            <?php
                $fn = $post->post_title;
                $name = str_replace('-', '_', $post->post_name);
                $num = strtok($fn, ' ');
                $availibility = types_render_field('plot-av', array('raw' => "true"));
                $points = explode('!!!', types_render_field('plot-path-points', array('show_name' => "false", 'separator' => '!!!'), null));
                $model = types_render_field('plot-type', array('raw' => "true"));
                $plotP = explode(',', types_render_field('plot-co', array('show_name' => "false"), null));
                $plotX = $plotP[0];
                $plotY = $plotP[1];
            ?>
            points[<?= $counter ?>] = [];
            plots[<?php echo $counter; ?>] = [];
            plots[<?php echo $counter; ?>]['name'] = '<?php echo $name ?>';
            plots[<?php echo $counter; ?>]['fn'] = '<?php echo $fn ?>';
            plots[<?php echo $counter; ?>]['num'] = '<?php echo $num ?>';
            plots[<?php echo $counter; ?>]['pX'] = '<?php echo $plotX ?>';
            plots[<?php echo $counter; ?>]['pY'] = '<?php echo $plotY ?>';              
            //if(Function('/*@cc_on return document.documentMode===9@*/')()){ 
            //if (window.ie == 9) { 
            //  console.log('ie9');
            //  plots[<?php echo $counter; ?>]['pY'] = plots[<?php echo $counter; ?>]['pY'] / 2;
            //}
            //if(Function('/*@cc_on return document.documentMode===10@*/')()){ 
            //  console.log('ie10'); 
            //  plots[<?php echo $counter; ?>]['pY'] = plots[<?php echo $counter; ?>]['pY'] / 2;
            //}
            if(document.documentMode >= 9){ 
            //  console.log('ie10'); 
                plots[<?php echo $counter; ?>]['pY'] = plots[<?php echo $counter; ?>]['pY'] / 2;
            }
            plots[<?php echo $counter; ?>]['availability'] = '<?php echo $availibility ?>';

            plots[<?php echo $counter; ?>]['points'] = <?php echo json_encode($points) ?>;
            <?php foreach($points as $i => $plot) { ?>
            plots[<?php echo $counter; ?>][<?= $i ?>] = '<?php echo $name; echo $i; ?>'
            <?php } ?>
            plots[<?php echo $counter; ?>]['model'] = '<?php echo $model ?>';
    <?php $counter ++; endwhile; wp_reset_query();?>
    window.spTooltip = '';
    window.spTooltopMore = '';
    window.onload = function() {
        var paper = Raphael('raphael-canvas', 1656, 1140);

        var plotLength = plots.length,
            curPlot = null;
        //  console.log(plotLength);
        for(var i = 0; i < plotLength; i++) {
            curPlot = plots[i];
             var curPlotPoints = curPlot['points'],
                 curPlotPointsLength = curPlotPoints.length,
                 indPlot = null,
                 plotAv = null;

            switch(curPlot['availability']) {
                case 'available':
                    plotAv = '#fff';
                    plotText = "<?= of_get_option('sp_available'); ?>";
                    break;                  
                case 'sold':
                    plotAv = '#ce0000';
                    plotText = "<?= of_get_option('sp_sold'); ?>";

                    break;
                case 'reserved':
                    plotAv = '#ce0000';
                    plotText = "<?= of_get_option('sp_reserved'); ?>";

                    break;
                case 'future':
                    plotAv = '#9E816D';
                    plotText = "<?= of_get_option('sp_release'); ?>";

                    break;
                case 'new':
                    plotAv = '#71b8ec';
                    plotText = "<?= of_get_option('sp_new'); ?>";

                    break;
                case 'options':
                    plotAv = '#fff';
                    plotText = "<?= of_get_option('sp_options'); ?>";

                    break;
            }

             for(var j = 0; j < curPlotPointsLength; j++) {
                indPlot = curPlotPoints[j];
                var convPlot = indPlot.replace(/([0-9.]+),([0-9.]+)/g, function($0, x, y) {
                        return 'L ' + Math.floor(x) + ',' + Math.floor(y) + ' ';
                    }).replace(/^L/, 'M'); // replace first L with M (moveTo)
                paper.path(convPlot + ' Z').attr({
                    fill: plotAv,
                    stroke: '#111111',
                    'stroke-width': '2',
                    'stroke-linecap': 'round',
                    'stroke-linejoin': 'round',
                    'stroke-miterlimit': '10'
                }).data({
                    'model': curPlot['model'],
                    'title': curPlot['fn'],
                    'status': curPlot['availability'],
                    'text': plotText,
                    'color': (plotAv == '#ce0000') ? 'color:#ce0000;' : ''
                }).hover(function() {
                    if(Modernizr.touch) {
                        if(this.data('status') == 'available') {
                            window.curHouseModel = this.data('title');
                            window.location.hash = this.data('model');
                        }
                    } else {
                        window.spTooltip = this.data('title') + '<i style="'+this.data('color')+'">' + this.data('text') + '</i>';
                        if(this.data('status') == 'available') {

                            $('body').css('cursor', 'pointer');
                        }
                    }
                }, function() {
                    window.spTooltip = '';
                    if(this.data('status') == 'available') {
                        $('body').css('cursor', 'default');
                    }

                }).click(function() {
                    var sdf = curPlot;
                //  console.log(sdf);
                //  console.log(curPlot);
                    if(this.data('status') == 'available') {
                        window.curHouseModel = this.data('title');
                        window.location.hash = this.data('model');
                    }
                });
             }
             paper.text(curPlot['pX'], curPlot['pY'], curPlot['num']).attr({
                'font-size': '12px',
                'font-weight': 'bold'
             }).data({
                    'model': curPlot['model'],
                    'title': curPlot['fn'],
                    'status': curPlot['availability'],
                    'text': plotText,
                    'color': (plotAv == '#ce0000') ? 'color:#ce0000;' : ''
                }).hover(function() {
                    window.spTooltip = this.data('title') + '<i style="'+this.data('color')+'">' + this.data('text') + '</i>';
                    if(this.data('status') == 'available') {
                        $('body').css('cursor', 'pointer');
                    }
                }, function() {
                    window.spTooltip = '';
                    if(this.data('status') == 'available') {
                        $('body').css('cursor', 'default');
                    }

                }).click(function() {
                    var sdf = curPlot;
                //  console.log(sdf);
                //  console.log(curPlot);
                    if(this.data('status') == 'available') {
                        window.curHouseModel = this.data('title');
                        window.location.hash = this.data('model');
                    }
                });

        }
        window.tt = $('.site-plan-tooltip');
        $(document).on('mousemove', function(e){
        //  console.log(e);
            if(window.spTooltip !== '') {
            //  console.log(window.spTooltip);
                var o = {};
                o.x = e.pageX - $('.modal-site-plan').offset().left + $('.modal-site-plan').scrollLeft(),
                o.y = e.pageY - $('.modal-site-plan').offset().top + $('.modal-site-plan').scrollTop(),
                o.w = $('.modal-inner-sp').width(),
                o.z = $('.modal-inner-sp').height();
                window.tt.show();
                if(o.x < (o.w / 2)) {
                    window.tt.css({
                        'right': 'auto',
                        "left": o.x+30,
                        "top": o.y+30
                    });
                } else {
                    window.tt.css({
                        "right": (o.w - o.x + 30),
                        'left': 'auto',
                        "top": o.y+10
                    });
                }
                if(o.y < (o.z / 2)) {
                    window.tt.css({
                        "top": o.y+30
                    });
                } else {
                    window.tt.css({
                        "top": o.y-90
                    });
                }
                window.tt.html(window.spTooltip);
            } else {
                window.tt.hide();
            }
        });
        function addTip(node, txt){
        //  console.log(node);
        }
    };

</script>
```

Solution I came up with:

```
var convPlot = indPlot.replace(/([0-9.]+),([0-9.]+)/g, function($0, x, y) {                           
                            return 'L ' + Math.floor(x) + ',' + Math.floor(y) + ' ';
                    });
                    var newConv = convPlot.replace('L','M'); // testing replace first L with M (moveTo)
                paper.path(newConv + ' Z').attr({
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first character in a path must be an M or m so the path is indeed invalid. You must have changed something in your software I imagine.

I guess you need to figure out why this line:

```
var convPlot = indPlot.replace(/([0-9.]+),([0-9.]+)/g, function($0, x, y) {
        return 'L ' + Math.floor(x) + ',' + Math.floor(y) + ' ';
    }).replace(/^L/, 'M'); // replace first L with M (moveTo)
```

isn't doing what the comment says that it should.

Comment: That's what doesn't make any sense is nothing has been changed to any of the code. The only thing that was recently changed was updating to WordPress 4.0 but that was done last week and the site plan was tested after that and worked fine up until 2 days ago.

Comment: I appreciate you pointing me in the right direction. No idea why that last line you mentioned just stopped working but I was able to re-write those lines of code in a way that worked again. Will share above just in case you or anyone is interested.